# Modify ant build process to build android jar

Tags: android, command-line, jar, ant, build

I inherited an in house build process that takes in some c static libraries and java wrapper classes, the build process creates a jar with the wraper classes using apache ant command line tool and this jar is what is used to consume the static libraries on Java SE and even on Android applications.

I recently added some android specific functions to the wrapper classes, this causes the ant build to fail as it was meant to only create jar from Java sources and only the jdk and not android sdk is referenced in the ant xml build instructions. My question is how do I modify the existing xml file to allow building from android sources to produce a jar archive that will work on Android. Here is the current build xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="identosjar" default="all">


  <property file="identosjar.properties"/>
  <!-- Uncomment the following property if no tests compilation is needed -->
  <!-- 
  <property name="skip.tests" value="true"/>
   -->

  <!-- Compiler options -->

  <property name="compiler.debug" value="on"/>
  <property name="compiler.generate.no.warnings" value="off"/>
  <property name="compiler.args" value=""/>
  <property name="compiler.max.memory" value="700m"/>
  <patternset id="ignored.files">
    <exclude name="**/*.hprof/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.pyc/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.pyo/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.rbc/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/*~/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/.DS_Store/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/.git/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/.hg/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/.svn/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/CVS/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/RCS/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/SCCS/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/__pycache__/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/_svn/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/rcs/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/vssver.scc/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/vssver2.scc/**"/>
  </patternset>
  <patternset id="library.patterns">
    <include name="*.war"/>
    <include name="*.swc"/>
    <include name="*.apk"/>
    <include name="*.zip"/>
    <include name="*.egg"/>
    <include name="*.ane"/>
    <include name="*.jar"/>
    <include name="*.ear"/>
  </patternset>
  <patternset id="compiler.resources">
    <exclude name="**/?*.java"/>
    <exclude name="**/?*.form"/>
    <exclude name="**/?*.class"/>
    <exclude name="**/?*.groovy"/>
    <exclude name="**/?*.scala"/>
    <exclude name="**/?*.flex"/>
    <exclude name="**/?*.kt"/>
    <exclude name="**/?*.clj"/>
    <exclude name="**/?*.aj"/>
  </patternset>

  <!-- JDK definitions -->

  <property name="jdk.bin.1.7" value="${jdk.home.1.7}/bin"/>
  <path id="jdk.classpath.1.7">
    <fileset dir="${jdk.home.1.7}">
      <include name="jre/lib/charsets.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/deploy.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/javaws.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/jce.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/jfr.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/jfxrt.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/jsse.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/management-agent.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/plugin.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/resources.jar"/>
      <include name="jre/lib/rt.jar"/>
      <include name="lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>
      <include name="lib/dt.jar"/>
      <include name="lib/javafx-doclet.jar"/>
      <include name="lib/javafx-mx.jar"/>
      <include name="lib/jconsole.jar"/>
      <include name="lib/sa-jdi.jar"/>
      <include name="lib/tools.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <property name="project.jdk.home" value="${jdk.home.1.7}"/>
  <property name="project.jdk.bin" value="${jdk.bin.1.7}"/>
  <property name="project.jdk.classpath" value="jdk.classpath.1.7"/>

  <!-- Modules -->


  <!-- Module IdentosJar -->

  <dirname property="module.identosjar.basedir" file="${ant.file}"/>


  <property name="module.jdk.home.identosjar" value="${project.jdk.home}"/>
  <property name="module.jdk.bin.identosjar" value="${project.jdk.bin}"/>
  <property name="module.jdk.classpath.identosjar" value="${project.jdk.classpath}"/>

  <property name="compiler.args.identosjar" value="-encoding UTF-8 -source 1.7 -target 1.7 ${compiler.args}"/>

  <property name="identosjar.output.dir" value="${module.identosjar.basedir}/out/production/IdentosJar"/>
  <property name="identosjar.testoutput.dir" value="${module.identosjar.basedir}/out/test/IdentosJar"/>

  <path id="identosjar.module.bootclasspath">
    <!-- Paths to be included in compilation bootclasspath -->
  </path>

  <path id="identosjar.module.production.classpath">
    <path refid="${module.jdk.classpath.identosjar}"/>
  </path>

  <path id="identosjar.runtime.production.module.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${identosjar.output.dir}"/>
  </path>

  <path id="identosjar.module.classpath">
    <path refid="${module.jdk.classpath.identosjar}"/>
    <pathelement location="${identosjar.output.dir}"/>
  </path>

  <path id="identosjar.runtime.module.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${identosjar.testoutput.dir}"/>
    <pathelement location="${identosjar.output.dir}"/>
  </path>


  <patternset id="excluded.from.module.identosjar">
    <patternset refid="ignored.files"/>
  </patternset>

  <patternset id="excluded.from.compilation.identosjar">
    <patternset refid="excluded.from.module.identosjar"/>
  </patternset>

  <path id="identosjar.module.sourcepath">
    <dirset dir="${module.identosjar.basedir}">
      <include name="src"/>
    </dirset>
  </path>


  <target name="compile.module.identosjar" depends="compile.module.identosjar.production,compile.module.identosjar.tests" description="Compile module IdentosJar"/>

  <target name="compile.module.identosjar.production" description="Compile module IdentosJar; production classes">
    <mkdir dir="${identosjar.output.dir}"/>
    <javac destdir="${identosjar.output.dir}" debug="${compiler.debug}" nowarn="${compiler.generate.no.warnings}" memorymaximumsize="${compiler.max.memory}" fork="true" executable="${module.jdk.bin.identosjar}/javac">
      <compilerarg line="${compiler.args.identosjar}"/>
      <bootclasspath refid="identosjar.module.bootclasspath"/>
      <classpath refid="identosjar.module.production.classpath"/>
      <src refid="identosjar.module.sourcepath"/>
      <patternset refid="excluded.from.compilation.identosjar"/>
    </javac>

    <copy todir="${identosjar.output.dir}">
      <fileset dir="${module.identosjar.basedir}/src">
        <patternset refid="compiler.resources"/>
        <type type="file"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="compile.module.identosjar.tests" depends="compile.module.identosjar.production" description="compile module IdentosJar; test classes" unless="skip.tests"/>

  <target name="clean.module.identosjar" description="cleanup module">
    <delete dir="${identosjar.output.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${identosjar.testoutput.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="init" description="Build initialization">
    <!-- Perform any build initialization in this target -->
  </target>

  <target name="clean" depends="clean.module.identosjar" description="cleanup all"/>

  <target name="build.modules" depends="init, clean, compile.module.identosjar" description="build all modules"/>

  <target name="init.artifacts">
    <property name="artifacts.temp.dir" value="${basedir}/__artifacts_temp"/>
    <property name="artifact.output.identos" value="${basedir}/out/artifacts/identos"/>
    <mkdir dir="${artifacts.temp.dir}"/>
    <property name="temp.jar.path.identos.jar" value="${artifacts.temp.dir}/identos.jar"/>
  </target>

  <target name="artifact.identos" depends="init.artifacts, compile.module.identosjar" description="Build &#39;identos&#39; artifact">
    <property name="artifact.temp.output.identos" value="${artifacts.temp.dir}/identos"/>
    <mkdir dir="${artifact.temp.output.identos}"/>
    <jar destfile="${temp.jar.path.identos.jar}" duplicate="preserve" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
      <zipfileset dir="${identosjar.output.dir}"/>
    </jar>
    <copy file="${temp.jar.path.identos.jar}" tofile="${artifact.temp.output.identos}/identos.jar"/>
  </target>

  <target name="build.all.artifacts" depends="artifact.identos" description="Build all artifacts">
    <mkdir dir="${artifact.output.identos}"/>
    <copy todir="${artifact.output.identos}">
      <fileset dir="${artifact.temp.output.identos}"/>
    </copy>

    <!-- Delete temporary files -->
    <delete dir="${artifacts.temp.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="all" depends="build.modules, build.all.artifacts" description="build all"/>
</project>
```

EDIT
The name of the ant file is identosjar.xml and as such the command is

ant -buildfile identosjar.xml

Also, the error

compile.module.identosjar.production:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/out/production/IdentosJar
    [javac] /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/identosjar.xml:154: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 12 source files to /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/out/production/IdentosJar
    [javac] /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/src/com/identos/Identos.java:4: error: package android.content does not exist
    [javac] import android.content.Context;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac] /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/src/com/identos/Identos.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         public int initialize(Context context, String appid, String clientkey, String version, boolean livemode, String filepath)
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Context
    [javac]   location: class Identos
    [javac] /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/src/com/identos/PlatformVerificationManager.java:3: error: package android.content does not exist
    [javac] import android.content.Context;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac] /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/src/com/identos/PlatformVerificationManager.java:4: error: package android.content.pm does not exist
    [javac] import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/src/com/identos/PlatformVerificationManager.java:5: error: package android.content.pm does not exist
    [javac] import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /Users/samuel.oyediran/SDK/build/android-arm/package/src/com/identos/PlatformVerificationManager.java:6: error: package android.content.pm does not exist
    [javac] import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

Comment: Where exactly is the build failing? Could you include the error message that you're getting, along with the full command you're running?

Comment: @CAustin I have added more information

Comment: Did you rename some of the targets in the script when you posted your question? I don't see any target containing "chimerajar" in your code.

Comment: @CAustin, yes I did, albeit lazily. I have now reverted everything to how it is in my ccode. Thank you

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with your Ant script, but it looks like the android jar library just isn't part of your classpath. Try including it as part of the fileset in `jdk.classpath.1.7`.